# Copy/move elision with a check

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision, noncopyable

Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/z/wodfLw). There is a non-copyable, non-movable class, and there is some predicated defined for it:

```
struct AA
{
    AA(AA const&  otehr) = delete;
    AA(AA      && otehr) = delete;
    AA& operator = (AA const&  otehr) = delete;
    AA& operator = (AA      && otehr) = delete;

    AA(int something) { }

    bool good() const { return false; }
};
```

Because of guaranteed [copy/move-elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) in C++17 we can have:

```
auto getA() { return AA(10); }
```

The question is: how can one define `getGoodA`, that will forward `getA` in case it returned `good` and will throw an exception otherwise? Is it possible at all?

```
auto getGoodA()
{
    auto got = getA();
    if (got.good()) return got; // FAILS! Move is needed.
    throw std::runtime_error("BAD");
}
```

Comment: What happens if you invert the check?  `if (!got.good()) throw std::runtime_error("BAD"); return got;` ?

Comment: Actually nothing. A move constructor will still be required.

Comment: @Vahagn Hopefully, this problem will be gone in C++23: wg21.link/p2025

Answer (score 2):

If we had got contract checking in C++20 you would have been able to write something like:

```
auto getGoodA(int i) [[post aa: aa.good()]] {
    return getA(i);
}
```

(At least I think so - I'm not entirely clear on the type of the `aa` return pseudo-variable; it would need to be a reference to the returned object in its return location.) Unfortunately contracts were [removed from C++20](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/cmk7ek/what_happened_to_c20_contracts/) so it'll be some time before we can write this.

Assuming you can't modify `getA`, the only way for now is to return a wrapper class from `getGoodA`. The obvious solution would be `unique_ptr`, but we don't actually need to perform heap allocation; a delayed-construction wrapper will [do just as well](https://godbolt.org/z/76BB8G):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>
struct BB {
    alignas(AA) std::byte buf[sizeof(AA)];
    template<class F, class G> BB(F f, G g) { g(*new (buf) AA{f()}); }
    BB(BB&&) = delete;
    ~BB() { reinterpret_cast<AA&>(buf).~AA(); }
    operator AA&() { return reinterpret_cast<AA&>(buf); }
    operator AA const&() const { return reinterpret_cast<AA const&>(buf); }
};
auto getGoodA(int i) {
    return BB{
        [&] { return getA(i); },
        [&](AA& aa) { if (!aa.good()) throw (struct bad**){}; }};
}
```

Here I've given `BB` a reference-style interface, allowing you to write `AA& aa = getGoodA(i)`, but you could equally give it a pointer-style interface (`operator*` and `operator->`) or even copy the interface of `AA`.